# type object 'HomePage' has no attribute 'signInBtn'

Tags: python, selenium

With help of a course I am trying to make page object model in python/selenium, my first shot that relied heavily on course went well, but second, more independent one have some unforeseen issues, although i tried to keep to similar principles i am getting some errors i did not had in my first try.

**conftest file**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pytest
from locators.locators import BasicInfo


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setUp(request):
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    request.cls.driver=driver
    driver.get(BasicInfo.URL)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

**Base Page**

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select



class BasePage:

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver=driver


def click(self,locator):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator).click()

def type(self,locator,text):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator).send_keys(text)

def clear(self,locator):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator).clear

def wait(self,locator):
    element=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element))

def mouseOver(self,locator):
    elem=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator)
    action=ActionChains(self.driver)
    action.move_to_element(elem).perform()

def textExtraction(self,locator):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,locator).text

def dropdown(self,locator, value):
    drop=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator)
    select=Select(drop)
    select.select_by_value(value)
```

**Home Page**

```
from locators.locators import HomePage, SignInPage, RegPage

from pages.basePage import BasePage


class HomePage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def goToRegistration(self, email):
        self.click(HomePage.signInBtn)
        self.type(SignInPage.regEmail, email)
        self.click(SignInPage.regBtn)
```

**Test file**

```
import pytest
from locators.locators import LoggedInPage
from pages.homePage import HomePage
from tests.baseTest import BaseTest
from utilities import dataGetter

class TestRegLog(BaseTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("email,firstname, lastname, pasw,company,address1,address2,city,zipcode, additinfo, phoneHome, phoneMobile, aliasAddress",dataGetter.dataGetter("Sheet1"))
    def test_regist(self, email, firstname, lastname, pasw, company, address1, address2, city, zipcode, additinfo, phoneHome, phoneMobile, aliasAddress):
        page=HomePage(self.driver)
        page.goToRegistration(email)
        page.fillRegForm(firstname, lastname, pasw,company,address1,address2,city,zipcode, additinfo, phoneHome, phoneMobile, aliasAddress)
        assert page.textExtraction(LoggedInPage.signOutBtn)=='''
            Sign out
        '''
```

**Error that i get is**

```
self = <pages.homePage.HomePage object at 0x000001EF6F5607F0>
email = <Cell 'Sheet1'.A2>

    def goToRegistration(self, email):
>       self.click(HomePage.signInBtn)
E       AttributeError: type object 'HomePage' has no attribute 'signInBtn'

..\pages\homePage.py:11: AttributeError
```

I reviewed my first try at framework like this, and i honestly don't see what am i doing wrong.

Comment: I organized locators in classes which i named HomePage, which is ambigous name, same as class with methods in home page. After changing locator class name i advanced to a next error.

Comment: I don't see where you have an attribute signInBtn within that object.

Comment: self.signInBtn = ""  should be initialized somewhere but it's missing.